# How to handle uploading files and nested Json to Flask?

Tags: flask

I'm attempting to implement the concurrent upload of files and nested Json to Flask.

Since Flask's `Request.form` is by default a `MultiDict[str, str]` you are limited to a flat data structure. In this scenario, would the standard approach be to encode the files in the Json on the client side and then decode once received on the server side? Or is there a more Flask oriented approach to implement this?

Comment: The standard flask approach to uploading files is to use request.files rather than request.form.

Comment: Using `request.files` requires the request to have the `multipart/form-data` header right? Flask will then provide the form data in `request.form` and the files in `request.files`. The problem I'm facing is that `request.form` is a `Multidict[str, str]` when I need a data structure like `Multidict[str, Any]` to accommodate my nested Json data.